# Is there a way to enable all macros in Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, macros

I just want the indexer to index entire code base irrespective of what macros are enabled or disabled. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are referring to conditionally compiled code enabled by macro definitions?  That being the case what you are asking for is unlikely to work in any meaningful way.  It may enable mutually exclusive code blocks that render the code non-parsable.

In a construct such as:

```
#if SOME_MACRO
  // some code
#else
  // some other code
#endif
```

Only `some code` section will be enabled.

Another example, what about the following?:

```
#if !defined SOME_MACRO
   // some code
#endif
```

In this case `some code` is enabled when the macro is *not defined*.

In short, "enabling all macros" will not achieve your aim - it will disable as much code as it enables and may render the code invalid and uncompilable in all but the most contrived circumstances.